# Why is the main thread being held when not awaiting at lowest level?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am new to asynchronous javascript and need some clarification.
So I have the following code:

```js
async function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function main() {
  while (true) {
    await delay(2000);
  }
}

main()
console.log(`Hi!`);
```

This works as expected, the main thread not being held by a promise and therefore "Hi!" being logged. However, when commenting out line 7 (`await delay(2000);`), "Hi!" isn't logged at all. Why does this happen?

Comment: Because it's an infinite loop, and never returns control to the main thread because it never calls `await`.

Comment: async functions run synchronously till the first await. Thus if you remove the await, the infinite loop will synchronously forever.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @Barmar Control doesn't need to return to the main thread, it never leaves the main thread. It's really just an infinite loop *on* the main thread. It doesn't return from the `main()` function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1

You can use [`.then()`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-async-functions#promise-returning) to await for the promise before logging.

```js
async function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function main() {
   await delay(2000);
}

main().then(x => console.log(`Hi! I'm delayed by 2 seconds!`));
```

### Solution 2

Logging inside the `main()` function.

```js
async function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function main() {
   await delay(2000);
   console.log(`Hi! I'm delayed by 2 seconds!`);
}

main();
```

But either way, you will have to remove the while loop.